# Bind query to props with vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Is it possible to bind query values to props declaratively?

I want `/my-foo?bar=my-bar` to pass the props `{foo: "my-foo", bar: "my-bar"}`.

I'm currently using something like this:

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/:foo",
      name: "Foo",
      component: FooPage,
      props: route => ({ foo: route.params.foo, bar: route.query.bar})
    }
  ]
});
```

And I'm looking for something like:

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/:foo?bar=:bar",
      name: "Foo",
      component: FooPage,
      props: true
    }
  ]
});
```

I'm using vue-router 2.3.1

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer is "no" as of now. Vue Router uses [`path-to-regexp`](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) for its path matching. Their documentation states: "The RegExp returned by path-to-regexp is intended for use with pathnames or hostnames. It can not handle the query strings or fragments of a URL."

Comment: How about putting query parameters parsing in the `mounted` of the component?

Answer (score 12):

I don't understand the problem with your current approach; solves your use case just fine.

That said, you could try [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), something like this:

```js
export default new Router({
  routes: [{
    path: "/:foo?bar=:bar",
    name: "Foo",
    component: FooPage,
    props: route => Object.assign({}, route.query, route.params)
  }]
})
```

... you can also try a more modern approach by using [*object spread*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (if you have [babel correctly configured](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread/)) ...

```js
route => ({ ...route.query, ...route.params })
```

Having `route.params` as the last merged/spread item avoids having querystrings overriding path parameters.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any declarative directive for that, but I do like [Ricardos general approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50782176/5185376). What might be a problem with that is that it unconditionally binds all query parameters as a prop, so one can modify any predefined props of that component just by adding it to the url.

If you want a filter and still reusability, you can define a helper function and bind the query in a less verbose way:

```
import bindQuery from "./router-query-bind";

export default new Router({
    routes: [{
        name: "Foo",
        path: "/:foo",
        props: bindQuery(["bar"]), // only binds 'bar' from query as a prop
        component: FooPage
    }, {
        name: "Bar",
        path: "/:bar",
        props: bindQuery(), // binds all query parameters as a props
        component: BarPage
    }]
});
```

With an implementation like the following. Note that this is TypeScript and has type annotations. Just remove them if you need plain JavaScript.

```
import { Route } from "vue-router";
type RoutePropsFunction = (route: Route) => Object;

/**
 * Creates a props-function for Vue-Router to pass all route parameters and query parameters as
 * props to the routed component.
 * You may filter the passed query parameters by name so that only the expected
 * props will be bound.
 * @param queryFilter List of query parameters which will be passed as props to the component.
 * This is optional. If not set all query parameters will be bound.
 */
export default function (queryFilter?: string[]): RoutePropsFunction {
    return function (route: Route) {
        const filtered = queryFilter ?
            queryFilter.reduce((a, b) => ({ ...a, [b]: route.query[b] }), {}) :
            route.query;
        return { ...route.params, ...filtered };
    }
}
```

Comment: "One can modify any predefined props of that component just by adding it to the url". That's true, but just changing the order and having `route.params` as the last merged/spread one should be enough to avoid having path params overwritten by querystrings.

Comment: Yes, but not if the prop is in the component itself and not in the URL parameters. Having a selective query parsing (I mean considering only some query params such as "pippo" and "pluto") is for me the best option