# How to access route query parameter when creating component?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

When I create or mount my component, this.$route.query is undefined, but it should contain the URL get parameters, eg. `?page=3`.

I'm making a paginated API browser.

Upon mounting my component, I'm constructing an object (to fetch data) that needs the URL query parameter `"page"` if it is present (`"/admin/trees?page=3"`).

When my component is mounted, however, `this.$route.query.page` is undefined for the first few hundred milliseconds. If I delay my object creation with setTimeout, `this.$route.query.page` is correctly set.

**How can I make sure `vue-router` has already processed the URL query when I run my component?**

While `setTimeout` works, it feels brittle and I don't understand why this is the case.

Following is the script section of my component:

```
<script>
import Forest from './forest'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data: () => ( { forest: [] } ),
  mounted: function() {
    setTimeout( () => {
      window.forest = Forest(this.fetchData, this.$route.query.page)
    }, 300)
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      this.forest = forest.trees
      this.total = forest.total
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried passing in the query params and props to your component in place of using `this.$route` ?  https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html

Comment: The point is to have a URL where the *user* can bookmark or alter the query parameter `?page=4` should bring him to the same pagination, i.e. page 4.

Comment: In other words, @Maurice - passing the query params from where?

Comment: From the router.  You configure your router to pass specific query params as props to the component. Take a look at the link I posted in my comment.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44783787/bind-query-to-props-with-vue-router) which suggests that this isn't possible, because the router uses [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) to process the request.

I suppose one could parse it oneself, but the confusion is why does it work with the Timeout and could it be made to work using Vue-Router built in parsing.

Comment: @icarito a little late to this discussion but i have the same issue, are you saying that vue components do not call $route.query watcher immediately upon loading?